# Vertical fixed navigation when sections aren't full height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using the following fixed navigation plug-in - https://codyhouse.co/demo/vertical-fixed-navigation/index.html

It works great when each section has 100% height as it picks the center of the section, but my sections aren't 100% height.

Is there a way to adapt this to work with smaller sections?

[Here's a fiddle I created](https://jsfiddle.net/uv7n2y2g/)

As you can see, it doesn't even highlight the top or bottom sections as they aren't in the center point of the screen.

JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var contentSections = $('.cd-section'),
        navigationItems = $('#cd-vertical-nav a');

    updateNavigation();
    $(window).on('scroll', function(){
        updateNavigation();
    });

    //smooth scroll to the section
    navigationItems.on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        smoothScroll($(this.hash));
    });
    //smooth scroll to second section
    $('.cd-scroll-down').on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        smoothScroll($(this.hash));
    });

    //open-close navigation on touch devices
    $('.touch .cd-nav-trigger').on('click', function(){
        $('.touch #cd-vertical-nav').toggleClass('open');

    });
    //close navigation on touch devices when selectin an elemnt from the list
    $('.touch #cd-vertical-nav a').on('click', function(){
        $('.touch #cd-vertical-nav').removeClass('open');
    });

    function updateNavigation() {
        contentSections.each(function(){
            $this = $(this);
            var activeSection = $('#cd-vertical-nav a[href="#'+$this.attr('id')+'"]').data('number') - 1;
            if ( ( $this.offset().top - $(window).height()/2 < $(window).scrollTop() ) && ( $this.offset().top + $this.height() - $(window).height()/2 > $(window).scrollTop() ) ) {
                navigationItems.eq(activeSection).addClass('is-selected');
            }else {
                navigationItems.eq(activeSection).removeClass('is-selected');
            }
        });
    }

    function smoothScroll(target) {
        $('body,html').animate(
            {'scrollTop':target.offset().top},
            600
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: When you say 100% height, do you mean100% of the screen height?

Comment: Yes, sorry I should have been more specific. My sections are not 100% browser height, same as in the fiddle. Is there a way to adapt this so that when the bottom of the browser hits the top of the div it highlights the section?

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by highlights this section? Like change the color highlight or do you want to completely center it?

Comment: Well, a class "is-selected" is added to the link tag on the floating navigation when you scroll to a section. This changes the colour of the floating navigation link depending on which section you are viewing. My problem is that because my section is not full height, it doesn't add this class.

Comment: Ok thanks I understand now.

Comment: To get the top to highlight add this in the middle of the conditional  inside of the `updateNavigation` function     `else if(!$(window).scrollTop() ){
          navigationItems.eq(0).addClass('is-selected');
               navigationItems.eq(activeSection).removeClass('is-selected');
   }`

Comment: I will do the other later when I have time.

Comment: Thanks mate! Yep, it's just the last item now that I need to try and workout.

Comment: You're welcome. I updated an answer.

Answer (score 1):

edit: make your section containers a % height. ex: height: 100% it will not work properly with a fixed height.

change your updateNavigation to look like this, don't copy and paste this as you can see the `if else` statement needs work to check if you are at the bottom of the page.

```
function updateNavigation() {
    contentSections.each(function(){
        $this = $(this);
        var activeSection = $('#cd-vertical-nav a[href="#'+$this.attr('id')+'"]').data('number') - 1;
        if ( ( $this.offset().top - $(window).height()/2 < $(window).scrollTop() ) && ( $this.offset().top + $this.height() - $(window).height()/2 > $(window).scrollTop() ) ) {
            navigationItems.eq(activeSection).addClass('is-selected');
        }
  else if(!$(window).scrollTop() ){
  navigationItems.eq(activeSection).removeClass('is-selected'); 
  navigationItems.eq(0).addClass('is-selected'); 
  }

  else if(check if you are at the bottom of the page not sure how){ 

  navigationItems.eq(activeSection).removeClass('is-selected'); 
  navigationItems.eq(navigationItems.length -1).addClass('is-selected'); 

  }else {
            navigationItems.eq(activeSection).removeClass('is-selected');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. It seems to almost be there, but the trouble is when the sections are different sizes. Sometimes it highlights more than one for example. Check here - https://jsfiddle.net/rct3gaqm/

Comment: That is because your section containers need a `height: 100%` or a non fixed style You can't expect it to work with a fixed height.